# faceting and x axis selection in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am working with this dataframe containing bit coin data from yahoo finance. I set a list of cryptocurrencies and I would like:
a. to limit the x axis to the last 2 months
b. try to put all the graphs together, like faceting one close to the other in a graph table, as it s possible to do in ggplot in R.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
%matplotlib inline

# For reading stock data from yahoo
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

# For time stamps
from datetime import datetime

# For division
from __future__ import division

tech_list = ['BTC','TTC','DGC','DEE','PPC']

end = datetime.now()
start = datetime(end.year - 1,end.month,end.day)

for stock in tech_list:   
    # Set DataFrame as the Stock Ticker
    globals()[stock] = DataReader(stock,'yahoo',start,end)

 DEE['Volume'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(10,4))
```

Should I change something in the time definition or in seaborn itself?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with `seaborn`, it is basic
`matplotlib` stuff. `seaborn` only changes the style of figures in
your case, so I exclude it from the code I provide below, but you can
import it if you want to change the style.

To get the data for the last 2 months you should make your `start` for two months before today. It is easy to do with `relativedelta`:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
start = dt.datetime(end.year,end.month,end.day) - relativedelta(months=2)
```

Changing limits of x axis would be more painful if you plot with `padnas.DataFrame.plot()`. But if you want to import all data and then select only data for the last 2 months, you can use the same `relativedelta` trick, but with indexing, like this:

```
DEE.loc[DEE.index >= end - relativedelta(months=2),'Volume'].plot()
```

As for putting the graphs together, your question is not phrased clearly, so I can only guess that you meant putting all stocks one under another as subplots, like this:

[image: subplots one under another]

I rewrote your code to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# For reading stock data from yahoo
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# For time stamps
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

end = dt.datetime.now()
start = dt.datetime(end.year-1,end.month,end.day)

tech_list = dict({'BTC':None,'TTC':None,'DGC':None,'DEE':None,'PPC':None})

for stock in tech_list.keys():   
    tech_list[stock] = DataReader(stock,'yahoo',start,end)

months_to_plot = relativedelta(months=2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))
for (n,stock) in enumerate(tech_list.keys()):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(len(tech_list),1,n)
    tech_list[stock].loc[tech_list[stock].index >= end - months_to_plot,'Volume'].plot()
    ax.set_title(stock)

plt.tight_layout()
```

P.S. Please be more clear in the future with your questions if you want a concise answer. The code you provided contains extra lines, not necessary for your question, which makes it more difficult to understand what exactly you want to do. Your question, on the other hand, is not nearly as detailed as it could be.